# What means "Insider Release" and "Production" on Windows Insider app?

Tags: insider-preview, windows-10-mobile

My Windows Insider updated and now it is showing four options:

- Insider Slow
- Insider Fast
- Insider Release Preview
- Production

I'm using *Insider Fast*, but what about other options?

If I choose *Insider Release* or *Production*, I will stop receive new updates from Windows 10?
What means this options?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [official Windows blog](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/02/10/announcing-windows-10-mobile-insider-preview-build-10586-107/):

> **Fast** – Best for Insiders who enjoy being the first to get access to
>   builds and feature updates, with some risk to their devices in order
>   to identify issues, and provide suggestions and ideas to make Windows
>   software and devices great.
>
> **Slow** – Best for Insiders who enjoy getting early access to builds and
>   feature updates, with less risk to their devices, and still want to
>   provide feedback to make Windows software and devices great.
>
> **Release Preview** – Best for Insiders who enjoy getting early access to
>   updates for the Current Branch, Microsoft applications, and drivers,
>   with minimal risk to their devices, and still want to provide feedback
>   to make Windows devices great.

**Production** is, to my understanding, the default set-up. Think of it as **stable**. To answer your question:

> If I choose Insider Release or Production, I will stop receive new updates from Windows 10?

In all options you will receive updates. What changes is the frequency. Starting from top (fast) with the most frequent updates and going to bottom (Production) with the least frequent updates. More frequent updates means more untested waters so possible bugs. You get to decide how much you care about bleeding edge. I personally use slow.

Answer (score 2):

- Production

  This will return your phone to the current publicly-available build. This was put in place to eliminate the need for a WRT install every time.
- Insider Release

  If I remember correctly, this will put you on the latest publicly-available build, but you will still get early access to app updates and things like that.

Comment: It will not return it to the stable version. It will just hold at the current preview version until the stable version catches up, then update as new productions are released. In order to roll back to the current stable version you have to reinstall Windows Phone Mobile.